# Flying in and out of Copenhagen. Do I need to go through security?

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, airport-security, cph

I will soon be travelling into Copenhagen from London, then from Copenhagen to Sorvagur (Faroe Islands) two hours after landing.
I will have no checked-in baggage. The two flights are operated by different airlines (booked separately). I will have checked in online for both flights. I am a UK citizen.

My question is:
Do I need to go through passport control, go to the departures area then go back through security to get to my next flight gate, or can I go directly there after landing?

Answer (score 3):

Arriving at CPH you will need to go through immigration (i.e. passport control) as you're coming from a non-Schengen country.

To get to the departure gate for the Faroe Islands you will [not need to go through security](https://www.cph.dk/en/practical/transfer/Gate-information/) (only non-EU arrivals go through security screening) and can go directly to your gate once you pass immigration. (Note: you might be lucky and your flight to the Faroe departs from the same area as your flight from the UK arrives - in that case you don't even need to pass through immigration. This is however not guaranteed.)

Comment: Does the OP have to go through immigration or not in Copenhagen? Your answer is that depending on his luck, he may or may not have to go through immigration. I highly doubt that luck is a relevant factor here.

Comment: I know that the Faroe Islands are not part of the Schengen agreement, but in practice I thought they didn't impose border controls between the Danish mainland and the Faroe Islands? This would suggest the flight would depart from within the Schengen area---not that it would really make any difference to an EU citizen.

Comment: @Calchas It sounds as if the OP is worried about not having enough time for immigration and security checks in Copenhagen. I just checked and at least today, the flights from CPH to FAE departed from the Schengen area. AFAIK that is also the current situation, but it means that when coming from London, the OP will have to pass immigration in Copenhagen.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Immigration is a non-event at CPH, takes five seconds to show your EEA passport. I think **canardgras** was more worried about security [since at many airports immigration control drops you into bag claim], but the way CPH is set up that won't be a problem on this connection.

Comment: @Calchas I flew to Faroe twice two years back - once departing from Schengen area, once from non-Schengen; not sure on current situation.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo _usually_ immigration is a non-issue for EEA nationals - I have experienced holdups at immigration for up to 45min, even fore EEA nationals though. (I fly through CPH very regularly - holdups are seldom; maybe once, max twice a year)